# How to remove starting 0's in uitextfield text in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, string, nsstring, texttrimming

Code Snippet:

> ```
>     NSString *tempStr = self.consumerNumber.text;        
>
>     if ([tempStr hasPrefix:@"0"] && [tempStr length] > 1) {
>         tempStr = [tempStr substringFromIndex:1];
>
>         [self.consumerNumbers addObject:tempStr];>           
>     }
> ```

I tried those things and removing only one zero. how to remove more then one zero

Output :001600240321

Expected result :1600240321

Any help really appreciated

**Thanks in advance !!!!!**

Comment: Thanks alot Dharmbir Choudhary....

Comment: Your welcome dear......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use this one

```
NSString *stringWithZeroes = @"001600240321";

NSString *cleanedString = [stringWithZeroes stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"^0+" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, stringWithZeroes.length)];

 NSLog(@"Clean String %@",cleanedString);
```

**Clean String 1600240321**

Comment: but this will remove o's at all places of string

Comment: @bhanu - Nope ... It wouldn't !!

Comment: @TheTiger Why not? Give me a input with false output

Comment: @LithuT.V - :) My reply was for `bhanu` ..... :)  I forgot to mention his name.

Comment: change range to NSMakeRange(0, stringWithZeroes.length-1) so string containing only zeros won't be changed to empty string (if required)

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary Vladimer didnt say it is wrong,In case the input string is 00000 then the empty string will be the output from your answer .To avoid that The suggestion is valid

Comment: ohh, sry @TheTiger my comment was for sunny to next ans

Answer (score 4):

convert string to int value and re-assign that value to string,

```
NSString *cleanString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [string intValue]];
```

`o/p:-`1600240321

Answer (score 0):

You can add a recursive function that is called until the string begin by something else than a 0 :

```
 -(NSString*)removeZerosFromString:(NSString *)anyString
{
    if ([anyString hasPrefix:@"0"] && [anyString length] > 1)
    {
        return [self removeZerosFromString:[anyString substringFromIndex:1]];
    }
    else
        return anyString;
}
```

so you just call in your case :

```
NSString *tempStr = [self removeZerosFromString:@"000903123981000"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"001600240321";
NSString *newStr = [@([str integerValue]) stringValue];
```

If the `NSString` contains numbers only.
Other wise use this:

```
-(NSString *)stringByRemovingStartingZeros:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = string;
    NSInteger count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<[string length]; i++)
    {
        if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[string characterAtIndex:i]] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            newString = [newString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i-count, 1) withString:@""];
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Simply call this method:-

```
NSString *stringWithZeroes = @"0000000016909tthghfghf";
NSLog(@"%@", [self stringByRemovingStartingZeros:stringWithZeroes]);
```

**OutPut: 16909tthghfghf**

Comment: what if str = 00123asdf ??

Comment: In this case down voted answer would also work. :) @LithuT.V I answered according to question not according to future requirement.

Comment: Which Question?there is no place saying he needs only for this and it is actually a loop in code being executed ,means it can be **dynamic** .So it is **Wrong**,That is why the answers are downvoted

Comment: @LithuT.V - See updated answer. Well We can answered what we see and never can read the minds... and If the question is cleared it is always better to answer. There can me many methods to do so.

Comment: @LithuT.V - See **zbMax** answer too. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString´ methode like this:

```
NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"0" withString:@""];
```

SORRY: This doesn't help you due to more "0" in the middle part of your string!

Comment: It will replace all zeros with blank space.